# Do I need transit visa for Dublin airport terminal 2?

Tags: dublin

I have a Canadian Travel document(not Canadian passport) and I plan to travel from Canada to Germany but I have a stop in Dublin (Terminal 2). I arrive (5:00 am) and leave(6:30 am) Dublin terminal 2 on the same day. Do i need transit visa for that?

Comment: Some people claimed in comments that Dublin/Ireland is in the Schengen area but that is not true.

Answer (score 1):

### 1954 Convention Travel Document holders:

> [Click here to check if you need an Irish visa](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/visit-ireland-travel-path/)
> See full country list: [Visa & Non-Visa Required Nationalities](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/visit-ireland-travel-path/)
> ...
> For all other situations, regardless of where you live, or the nationality of your family member, your needing an Irish Visa or Preclearance is based on:
>
> - your nationality (if you are not a refugee); or
> - **the country which issued your Travel Document (if you are a refugee)**.
>
> All other *1954 Convention Travel Document* holders will, unless otherwise exempt (see exemptions <strike>above</strike> [below]), need a visa.
>
> > Exemptions: from Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, Germany, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovak Republic, Spain, Sweden, or Switzerland,

This information is also contained on this page with a additional note:

- [Recognition of Convention Travel Documents - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-work-in-ireland/what-are-my-options-for-working-in-ireland/coming-to-work-for-less-than-90-days/join-ship-visa/recognition-of-convention-travel-documents/)

> **Note**: If you possess a convention travel document issued by another country, you will require a visa.

Since Canada is not listed here, it looks as if you require a Transit visa.

> [Transit (including Transfer Visa) Advice - Immigration Service Delivery](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/)
> ...
> Transit passengers making connections at Dublin Airport should be aware of the following: If both your arrival flight and onward connecting flight are in Terminal 2 between the hours of 04:00 and 16:00 on the same day, you can use a transit visa in this case.
> ...

Comment: I think this answer reaches a correct conclusion (the OP needs a visa) but takes an unnecessary detour. [This Irish Government webpage](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/) directly addresses the transit visa question. As to Irish transit: Refugee Travel Documents aren't mentioned at all. Because we don't know the OP's home country, we don't know (yet) if the OP needs a transit visa. I will post a separate answer.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Your link is the same as my second link ('Transit (including Transfer Visa) Advice') and leads to my first link which contains a popup dialog from where the relavent information was taken from (and cannot be linked to directly).

Answer (score 1):

[This Irish Department of Justice webpage](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/at-the-border/transit-including-transfer-visa-advice/) specifically addresses the Irish Transit Visa. The page says:

> **Transit Visa Required Countries**
>
> - Afghanistan
> - Albania
> - Cuba
> - Democratic Republic of Congo
> - Eritrea
> - Ethiopia*
> - Georgia
> - Ghana
> - Iran
> - Iraq
> - Lebanon
> - Moldova
> - Nigeria
> - Somalia
> - Sri Lanka
> - Ukraine
> - Zimbabwe
>
> *Travel from Ethiopia to USA or Canada or Ethiopia from USA or Canada, via Ireland.
>
> You do not need an Irish transit visa if you are a citizen of Ethiopia and are travelling on your national passport directly from Ethiopia via Ireland to the United States or Canada. You must have permission to travel to the United States or Canada.
>
> You will not need a transit visa to travel directly from the United States or Canada back to Ethiopia via Ireland. You must have been legally in the United States or Canada at the time of your departure.

Note that the page addresses only the identity of the traveler's home country, and does not mention Refugee Travel Documents. Holding a Refugee Travel Document, or the identity of the country that issued the Refugee Travel Document, is therefore irrelevant.

Thus, if your home country is listed on this Irish Government webpage, then you will need a Transit visa to change planes in Dublin, Ireland.

***You may also need a separate visa to enter Germany, which is in the Schengen area and follows different visa and entry rules.***

Comment: Relevent is that the OP has a **Travel document** and not their citizenship. See my answer where this is quoted and that a **Travel document** issued  in Canada is not exempted from the visa requirement.